# Prevent browser from saving page in cache

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, caching, ejs

I'm working on a website with nodejs, express and ejs.
The issue is that when an user logouts, he still sees the website as if he was logged in.
How can I fix this? I have already tried adding:

```
    <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate">
    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
    <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">
```

but the issue persists

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do we control web page caching, across all browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/how-do-we-control-web-page-caching-across-all-browsers)

Comment: You can check also [Using meta tags to turn off caching in all browser (Stack Overflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341089/using-meta-tags-to-turn-off-caching-in-all-browsers) that is another duplicate